# Sum total of several MySQL columns stored in another column?

Tags: mysql

I have several columns in a MySQL database that I would like to add and store in another column:

```
column1     column2     column3    subtotal
10          10          10         30
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to store the subtotal? If you need to get it, you can just SELECT *, (col1 + col2 + col3) AS subtotal FROM table;

Comment: do you want to physically store in a column on a table or run an sql to get the above display

Comment: I need the subtotal stored in a column.  The column (subtotal)will be echoed in an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
UPDATE tableName SET subtotal = (column1 + column2 + column3)
```

### Update 1

If you really don't need subtotal column in table just use query as

```
SELECT *, (column1 + column2 + column3) as subtotal
FROM tableName
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/203e2/2)

Answer (score 4):

```
update yourtable set subtotal = col1 + col2 + col3
```

Comment: You forgot step one: apt-get install postgres.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm very new to Mysql.  More familiar with excel.  Is it possible to save that formula/query as a value for the column or do I have to manually update?  Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: You could write a trigger that updates the `subtotal` field if a column value changes. But it is more common not to save redundant information and calculate the subtotal when you select your data from the table

Comment: You should rather be doing this: `select col1, col2, col3, (col1+col2+col3) as subtotal from yourtable`

Answer (score 1):

If you simply update subtotal, you have to *maintain* its value - ie every time one of the other columns is updated, your code has to remember to update subtotal too.

There are two ways to address this issue:

1. Create a trigger that fires when the row is updated. This option requires database "kung fu" and isn't immediately obvious to anyone else looking at the table the the trigger exists
2. Create a `VIEW` that does the calculation

I think option 2 is the best approach.

Here's how you code a view.

```
create view mytable_totalled as
select col1, col2, col3,  col1 + col2 + col3 as subtotal
from mytable
```

Once created, the view can be used just like a table (with a few caveats), but you can certainly do any kind of select on it. The new column is calculated on the fly when selected

Answer (score 0):

Well if this is just a one time deal you could do an update query like so:

```
UPDATE MyTable set subtotal = (column1 + column2 + column3)
```

If you want it to be calculated on insert, you could have a calculated column.

I would personally just wait until you need it to calculate it so that information that could easily be derived from your data isn't bloating your DB.